# R: Extract words from a website

Tags: r, regex, rvest

I am attempting to extract all words that start with a particular phrase from a website. The website I am using is:

http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/

I want to extract all the words that start with "stat_". I should get 21 names like "stat_identity" in return. I have the following code:

```
 stats <- readLines("http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/")
 head(stats)

 grep("stat_{1[a-z]", stats, value=TRUE)
```

I am returned every line containing the phrase "stat_". I just want to extract the "stat_" words. So I tried something else:

```
 gsub("\b^stat_[a-z]+ ", "", stats)
```

I think the output I got was an empty string, " ", where a "stat_" phrase would be? So now I'm trying to think of ways to extract all the text and set everything that is *not* a "stat_" phrase to empty strings. Does anyone have any ideas on how to get my desired output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rvest` & `stringr` to the rescue:

```
library(xml2)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

pg <- read_html("http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/")

unique(str_match_all(html_text(html_nodes(pg, "body")),
                     "(stat_[[:alnum:]_]+)")[[1]][,2])
##  [1] "stat_bin"                 "stat_bin2dCount"         
##  [3] "stat_bindot"              "stat_binhexBin"          
##  [5] "stat_boxplot"             "stat_contour"            
##  [7] "stat_density"             "stat_density2d"          
##  [9] "stat_ecdf"                "stat_functionSuperimpose"
## [11] "stat_identity"            "stat_qqCalculation"      
## [13] "stat_quantile"            "stat_smooth"             
## [15] "stat_spokeConvert"        "stat_sum"                
## [17] "stat_summarySummarise"    "stat_summary_hexApply"   
## [19] "stat_summary2dApply"      "stat_uniqueRemove"       
## [21] "stat_ydensity"            "stat_defaults"
```

Unless you *need* the links (then you can use other `rvest` functions), this removes all the markup for you and just gives you the text of the website.

Comment: Side note: version `0.3.0` of `rvest` automatically loads package `xml2`.

Comment: aye, but i like to avoid the "loading required package…" messages whenever possible

Comment: hrbrmstr and Pascal, you guys are life savers! Thank you so much for knowing R! :)